# Missing custom headers in webview' goBack() requests

Tags: android, webview, http-headers

I'm adding custom headers to all webview's requests by calling:

```
webview.loadUrl(url, myHeaders)
```

and overloading webview client's:

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading()
```

When browsing and going deep-linking, all requests have custom headers but all webview's `goBack()` requests don't. `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is not invoked when `goBack()` is called.

I'm wondering how to ensure that custom headers are always included in `goBack()` requests?

Answer (score 0):

Normally WebView re-sends extra headers when going back in navigation history, I have briefly tested that and it seems to work. However, there are several moments that can be confusing, so I would advise to re-check what is really happening in your scenario:

1. WebView may not even re-contact the server in order to load the page when you call `goBack()` -- it can just restore the page from the cache. In order to force re-querying the page from the server, the latter must disable caching of the page using `cache-control` header: `cache-control: no-cache,no-store`. And in that case, if the page was loaded via `loadUrl` with extra headers, these headers will be re-sent.
2. If the user clicks a link on a page loaded with extra headers, these headers are not "inherited" by the page you are navigating to (the same is true for navigations done by JS code). Thus, if you are calling `goBack` and the previous page has been loaded from a user click, it will not have any extra headers of the starting page loaded via `loadUrl`.
3. `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is only called for loads caused by user or server actions, not for loads initiated via WebView API methods, like `loadUrl` or `goBack`, because the app already knows that it is about to navigate WebView somewhere. For example, if you are loading `google.com` via `loadUrl`, the original navigation will not be intercepted by `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, but the redirect that the server does, e.g. to the `https` page, will be.

Hope it helps. If you still suspect WebView in not re-sending extra headers, I would strongly advise preparing a simple repro case that would demonstrate it.